# Read and sum occurrence lines in bash

Tags: bash

I have a file that includes lines below separated by comma ;

filename.txt

```
usernameA,10,10
usernameB,20,20
usernameA,10,10
usernameB,20,20
usernameC,10,10
```

I just want to parse the file and add numbers by username if occurs multiple times , so the result should be ;

```
usernameA=40
usernameB=80
usernameC=20
```

How can i achive this result using Bash script ?

Thank you,

Comment: what did you try? we have tons of questions like this

Comment: i bet there are. If you do a favour , point me out to the mentioned link that i couldn't find out and delete the question :)

Comment: Try to use 'awk'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$1]+=$2+$3}END{for(x in a)print x "=" a[x]}' file
usernameA=40
usernameB=80
usernameC=20
```

This works for the given example.

Comment: does it possible to use in an array ? So i need to parse the file using arrays then find the result as a variable in bash. The real picture does not that simple.

Comment: it is possible. you can extend my answer.